# Java queue errors

Tags: java, list, queue

I keep getting the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2. When i pop and peek after pushing one value into it says null. And when i pop/peek from an empty queue it gives me the error. Is this not the correct way to use artay list with a queue?

```
 public T peek()
        {
            if(isEmpty())
                throw new RuntimeException("Can't peek here");

            return value.get(value.size()-1););
        }

public T pop()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't pop here");

        T number = value.get(begin);
        value.set(begin, null);
        //value.remove(value.size()-1);

        begin++;
        return number;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after you get `begin`, you immediately set it to null. When you set `begin` to null, you also set `number` to null, because number and begin reference the same object.

The correct way to "pop" from a queue is as follows:

- Reference first item
- Remove item from list
- Return reference

In code, it looks like this. For my example, I assumed that `value` is your ArrayList. Perhaps `values` would be a less confusing name.

```
T number = value.get(0); // Reference the first item
value.remove(0) // Remove it from the list
return number; // Return the reference
```

You should check that your list isn't empty before performing any of these operations.

```
if(val.size() > 0) {
    // Do Stuff
} else {
    throw CannotPopFromAnEmptyQueueException();
}
```

It's worth mentioning that "pop" is not a good term when talking about a Queue. **Enqueue** and **Dequeue** are the more formal terms. **Pop** and **push** are stack terminology.

Answer (score 0):

After first pop/peek, you will have one element in your queue with value equal to "null"

PSB the excerpt from your code:

```
T number = value.get(begin);
value.set(begin, null);
//value.remove(value.size()-1);

begin++;
```

In the first iteration begin would be equal to 0. So, you are doing something like value.set(0, null) and begin++, so begin=1 now.

So when next time you go and do pop/peek, you actually try to fetch the element at index 1 which is not there, hence you are getting this indexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Exactly, you shouldn't increment like this. In your case you can probably check for the size of your arraylist and make sure that begin counter never goes beyond that size after an increment.